# HBase MapReduce ，Multi-table operation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, multi-table

There are two HBase Tables(table1, table2) as input source, using MapReduce to compare one column in table1 with one column in table2, if the one in table1 is equivalent with the one in table2, output them to table3.

How can we solve the problem using MapReduce? (Hadoop2.2.0+Hbase0.96.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step - go through this link to understand how Hbase Table can be source to a mapper: [Hbase Table as Mapper source](http://hbase.apache.org/book/mapreduce.example.html)

Next step coming to your specific problem:
You will have 2 Mappers (i.e. 2 inputs) one for each table.
You reduce based on values from the tables. You may need a complex key or something in value to specify which table value came from in Reducer. In reducer if the value/key came from both tables i.e. both mappers, then you can use Hbase API (Link above explains a bot of that also) to write to a table.